# Display the sum of both sides in 2-D array

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulties in displaying the sum of each row and column in the magic square. My algorithm of the magic square is fine but when I'm trying to display the sum of each side it kinds of messing up my magic square and it gives me large and negative values. I have a hunch that it was something to do with my indexing and I am spending quite some time figuring out why I can't display it properly. any help would be appreciated ty.

A magic square is an arrangement of the numbers from 1 to n^2 (n-squared) in an nxn matrix, with each number occurring exactly once, and such that the sum of the entries of any row, any column, or any main diagonal is the same. It is not hard to show that this sum must be n(n^2+1)/2.

to solve this place 1 at the first row middle of the square then for the next number move up then left, if the index is occupied place it 1 down row.

sorry i am not that good in explaining it in English. thanks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n,x,y;

    cout<<"Enter size of the magic square " <<endl;
    cout<<"Must be odd number starting from 3: ";
    cin>>n;
    while(n%2==0){              //condtion if the entered value is even
        cout<<"Please Enter Odd number: ";
        cin>>n;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n";

    int array[n][n];            //create 2d matrix

    for( x=0;x<n;x++){              //initialize the value of your 2d matrix as 0
        for( y=0;y<n;y++){
            array[x][y] = 0;        
        }   
    }



    int row = 0;            //your row starting position
    int col = n/2;          //your colum starting position

    array[row][col] =1;     //position of your first counting number 

    for (int i = 2; i <= n*n; ++i)      //this is working   algorith is up left
    {
        if((i-1)%n == 0)            //if it is occupied go down
        {
            row++;
        }
        else  
        {
            row--;               
            row = (row+n)%n;

            col -=1;
            col%=n-1;
        }
        if (col<0){
            col = col+n;
        }
        array[row][col] = i;


    }                               //up to here


    for(x=0;x<n;x++){               //display sum in the side
        for(y=0;y<n;y++){
            array[x][n]+=array[x][y];
        }
    }

    for(x=0;x<n;x++){               //display sum at the bottom
        for(y=0;y<n;y++){
            array[n][x]+=array[x][y];
        }
    }

    for(x=0;x<=n;x++){              //display your matrix.
        for(y=0;y<=n;y++){
            cout<<"\t" <<array[x][y]  <<"  ";   
        }
        cout<<"\n\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add a problem statement of what magic square means here.

Comment: int columns should be (n+1)/2, not n/2 ?

Comment: `int array[n][n]` is not valid in C++, you should dynamically allocate space.

Comment: i think its the same since the magic square is odd number so regardless you use (nt1)/2 or n/2 it still will placed at the middle. ty

Comment: @xiaofeng thanks for replying. im not familiar about the term dynamically allocate space but im not having problems creating 2d array.

Comment: *but im not having problems creating 2d array.* -- This is why the compiler you're using, probably `g++`, should by default turn **off** this option of allowing creating non-standard, non-C++ arrays.  All it does is make new programmers believe they are writing C++ code, when they're not.  This `int array[n][n];` is not C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of

```
int array[n][n];            //create 2d matrix
```

is supported only on some platforms as an extension. I strongly suggest changing it to use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;
```

Also, you use:

```
        array[n][x]+=array[x][y];
```

and

```
        array[x][n]+=array[x][y];
```

Those lines cause undefined behavior since `n` is not a valid index.

Also, in both cases, you are accumulating the values from the row. The second line needs to accumulate the values from the column. You need to use `array[y][x]`.

You would like to display the sum of the rows and sum of the columns as the final output along with the elements of the 2D array. For that, it will be easier to create a `n+1 X n+1` matrix. You can do that by using:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(n+1, std::vector<int>(n+1));
```

The logic for computing the sum of the rows and storing them in the `n+1`-th column needs to be:

```
for(x=0;x<n;x++){
   array[x][n] = 0;
   for(y=0;y<n;y++){
     array[x][n] += array[x][y];
   }
}
```

The logic for computing the sum of the columns and storing them in the `n+1`-th row needs to be:

```
for(x=0;x<n;x++){
  array[n][x] = 0;
  for(y=0;y<n;y++){
     array[n][x] += array[y][x];
  }
}
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/XBzUr0.

Comment: thanks for the help. im using dev c++ so vectors giving me some kind of errors, i just add +1 to my 2d matrix  int array[n+1][n+1] and it solved my problems. later i will look in to vectors and it seems it can make my code shorter. thanks again to you and those that replies, god bless.